# Javascript credit card expiry date validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using javascript validation to validate that the user inputs a valid date, however, my current regex patterns do not validate that the user must not be able to input a date less than 03/19. Instead, it allows 01/19 and also 02/19 etc.

I believe there are other ways to do this verification in javascript however I was wondering if there was a way with this regex.

current javascript:

```
var errdiv = $(".error");
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      cardmm: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 2,
        pattern: "^(1[0-2]|[0-9]|)$"
      },
      cardyy: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 2,
          pattern: "^(2[0-8]|19|)$"
      },
    },
    messages: {
      cardmm: {
        required: "Please enter valid details.",
        minlength: "Please enter valid details.",
        maxlength: "Please enter valid details.",
        max: "Please enter valid details.",
        pattern: "Please enter valid details."
      },
      cardyy: {
        required: "Please enter valid details.",
        minlength: "Please enter valid details.",
        maxlength: "Please enter valid details.",
        pattern: "Please enter valid details."
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element, m) {
      errdiv.css({"display": "block"});
      errdiv.empty();
      errdiv.text(error[0].innerHTML);
    },
    success: function(error) {
        error.removeClass("error");  // <- no, no, no!!
        errdiv.css({"display": "none"});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please add a few inputs and expected outputs

Comment: These fields are connected to each other. You can't validate it like this. You will have to create a custom validator which will check both fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could break the problem into 2 pieces: a regex for any date with year greater than 2019, and another for the specific months you want to allow for 2019, then combine them into your final regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could always invoke a little script that combines the mm and yy fields
of the form to validate as a whole.

Join the fields with a forward slash.

The validation regex is then:

`^(?:(?:0?[3-9]|1[0-2])/19|(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/2[0-8])$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?: 0? [3-9] | 1 [0-2] )
      /19
   |  
      (?: 0? [1-9] | 1 [0-2] )
      /2 [0-8] 
 )
 $
```

Otherwise, it really can't be validated separately.